# Bypass "Do you want to..." dialog after clicking script

Tags: scripts, dialog

After I create a bash script and double click it in Nautilus I am prompted with this - Do you want to run "sleepytime", or display its contents? With Run in terminal, Dislpay, Cancel and Run as options.

[image]

Is it possible to just choose "run" or "run in terminal" by default?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Nautilus, choose **Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Behavior ▸ Executable Text Files ▸ Run executable text files when they are opened**.

Comment: gracias @ændrük

Comment: Can we change the behaviour for a specific file only?

Comment: @errikos Not with this method. I'd ask that as a new question with details about your specific needs in case there are alternative solutions you'd find suitable, e.g. a .desktop file linking to your script.

Comment: TIL the file explorer in Ubuntu is called Nautilus :)